# Symmetric product and seminormality (curve case)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $d$ be a positive integer. Is the $d$-symmetric product of a nodal curve over a field seminormal?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I think Michael Van Opstall may have proved this in his thesis (I remember talking to Michael about this in his office when we were both graduate students at UW).  I don't have time to look it up right now though.  You could also check *Moduli of products of stable varieties* by Bhatt, Ho, Patakfalvi and Schnell.

Comment: @Karl Schwede thank you for the references but still I need the symmetric product case not simply the product. For smooth curves the symmetric product is still smooth and I would like to say the same in the seminormal case assuming that I know that the product is seminormal.

Comment: Hi, I realize you mean symmetric product, and I remember discussing this with Michael.  Does he only do the product case?

Comment: @KarlSchwede thanks for replying. If I understand correctly yes. This is proposition 3.1 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307094v2.pdf . If I knew normality, I would have that the quotient is still normal, because the group acting is finite. But for seminormal I don't know how to prove that also the quotient is seminormal.

Comment: Probably the right thing to search for, in this part of the literature, is that a quotient of SLC singularities is SLC (SLC = semi-log canonical).  You can try perhaps the recent book of Kollar and Kovacs?

Comment: If a ring $R \subseteq S$ is a finite extension, $R$ is a summand of $S$ and $S$ is S2, then so is $R$.  Perhaps this could be used ($R$ is an affine chart of the symmetric product, $S$ is the ordinary product)?  Anyway, I'm sure such quotients must be S2.